# Document structure : add localizable field?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I need to create a new document type with a localizable "Description" field.
I've added a textbox field, and i've set localizable = yes
But when i create a new document using this document type, i cannot give some translation for my field.
Did i miss something? (i'm on Liferay 6.2)
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you defined only one language in your `portal-ext.properties`?

Comment: i just tried to add some languages in portal-ext but nothing changed :/

Answer (score 0):

Liferay supports localized document fields, but GUI is not much helpful here. It hides the feature completely.

How to set the localized values:

1. Create document of your type and provide values in the default language (currently displayed language).
2. Save the document.
3. Change the language of the admin console by manipulating the url - Insert the language code before `/group/control_panel/manage` fragment. Example for changing the language to Czech ('cs' language code) - http://localhost:8080**/cs**/group/control_panel/manage?...
4. Edit the document and provide values in the new language.
5. Save the document.

You can verify the data in the database - the custom fields are stored in DDMCONTENT table (column XML). For example:

```
<root>
    <dynamic-element default-language-id="en_US" name="localizedText">
        <dynamic-content language-id="en_US"><![CDATA[cat]]></dynamic-content>
        <dynamic-content language-id="cs_CZ"><![CDATA[kocka]]></dynamic-content>
    </dynamic-element>
</root>
```

Answered for Liferay 6.2.

Comment: I tried but it only update values everytime i save  :/